# how does omitNull work in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a raw query something like this:

```
select c1,c2 
from table1 t1
where 
   t1.name :var1 AND t1.number = :var2
```

var1 and var2 are bind variables.

Is it possible for a bind variable to be NULL. Like, if we have,

```
var1 = 'abc', var2 = NULL;
```

I need the resulting query to be like:

```
select c1,c2 
from table1 t1
where 
   t1.name = 'abc'
```

and not

```
select c1,c2 
from table1 t1
where 
   t1.name = 'abc' AND t1.number = NULL
```

I am passing `{omitNull: true}` in the Sequelize config (which from the doc, seems to be saying what I'm expecting in my case above), but it's not working.

How to get this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's what `omitNull` does. From the docs

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/

```
A flag that defines if null values should be passed to SQL queries or not.
```

From what I understand it only affects insert or update options excluding the where clauses and entirety of raw queries.

You probably have to create two separate queries to achieve this.